# 'Image' object has no attribute 'shape'; Pytorch Object Detection

Tags: image, pytorch, object-detection, attributeerror, torchvision

I doing object detection with Pytorch/Torchvision with this tutorial, which is very similar to the official pytorch Tutorial.

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae

While training the model, execution stops after set epochs and gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     26         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     27             with self.__class__():
---> 28                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     29         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     30 

/content/Pytorch_OD/My Drive/Pytorch_OD/vision/engine.py in evaluate(model, data_loader, device)
     78     header = 'Test:'
     79 
---> 80     coco = get_coco_api_from_dataset(data_loader.dataset)
     81     iou_types = _get_iou_types(model)
     82     coco_evaluator = CocoEvaluator(coco, iou_types)

/content/Pytorch_OD/My Drive/Pytorch_OD/vision/coco_utils.py in get_coco_api_from_dataset(dataset)
    204     if isinstance(dataset, torchvision.datasets.CocoDetection):
    205         return dataset.coco
--> 206     return convert_to_coco_api(dataset)
    207 
    208 
/content/Pytorch_OD/My Drive/Pytorch_OD/vision/coco_utils.py in convert_to_coco_api(ds)
    157         img_dict = {}
    158         img_dict['id'] = image_id
--> 159         img_dict['height'] = img.shape[-2]
    160         img_dict['width'] = img.shape[-1]
    161         dataset['images'].append(img_dict)

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'shape
```

'Image' is imported via `from PIL import Image`.

The attribute `shape` is not being defined in the code in my notebook.

**Can it be that itis an error in the source file of `coco_utils.py`?**

**Or do I need to provide more information or parts of my code?**